# Can I compile a function containing ArcTanh?

Tags: compile

Can I compile a function that contains ArcTanh[]? The following doesn't work

```
Needs["CCodeGenerator`"]
c = Compile[ {{x}}, ArcTanh[x]^2];
c[2.5]
```

*Mathematica* gives me

> ```
> "CompiledFunction::cfn: Numerical error encountered at instruction 1;
>  proceeding with uncompiled evaluation>>"
> ```

However, in the answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) question, a reply indicates that `ArcTanh` can be compiled.

Comment: The values of $\tanh x$ are between -1 and 1 for real arguments.  If you wish to work with complex numbers, use the appropriate type annotation in `Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, ...]`.

Answer (score 13):

The values of $\tanh x$ are between -1 and 1 for real arguments.  `ArcTanh[x]` yields a complex answer if `x` is not between -1 and 1.  `Compile` does support complex numbers, but you need to specify this using a type annotation:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, ArcTanh[x]^2];
cf[2.5]

(* ==> -2.28792 - 1.33093 I *)
```

If you allow for complex inputs in `cf`, it'll be able to return complex results as well.

---

Side note: you don't need to load `` CCodeGenerator` `` to use `Compile`.